# How to choose GPS setup?

Tags: gps, gis, qgis

I need some advice on choosing a GPS set-up to map estuarine habitats in the field.

Our SA estuaries are often very narrow (1 to 2 km wide) and habitats are  small.
We distinguish between supra-tidal salt marsh, inter-tidal salt marsh, reeds and sedges, among other habitats. Reeds and sedges often form a very narrow band along an estuary.  Accuracy needs to be as close as possible to 1m², perhaps even better.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: A GPS tells you where you are, sometimes in great detail, to several decimal points in degree seconds, but the consumer level GPS in the US is limited to about a 10ft margin of error. You will be within +-10ft (about 3 meters) of what the GPS tells you. I'm not sure exactly how you wanted to map things. Did you want to map where different habitat types in the area? Are you hooking up a GPS unit to an Ubuntu laptop you will take in the field? Did you want to go out in the field, when you reach the edge of a habitat, you click on a map to tell it "this is a supratidal salt marsh"?

Comment: Where is the relation with Ubuntu?!

Comment: [Are there any standard formats for storing/publishing GPS data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931270/are-there-any-standard-formats-for-storing-publishing-gps-data), that's just for the standard formats and after that I guess he wants to know a good way of storing all of the GPS data.

Comment: This question would fit better at [GIS.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com). But even there this question will sound somewhat vague. You must at least specify which spatial variables are you exactly interested in.